# Automation workflow from Github using node 18.16.0 with webdriverio (using typescript) -throws at listOnTimeout ,processTimers

Tags: node.js, github-actions, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

Automation workflow from Github using node 18.16.0 with webdriverio (using typescript) using github hosted runner -throws at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) error

After upgrading node from 14.21.3 to 18.16.0 i am getting error
Error: Timeout
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

Current runner version: '2.309.0'
Ubuntu - 22.04.3

Tried all the way to change the timeout property in wdio.shared.conf file .